# Exception Passing Through scala.concurrent.Future?

Tags: scala, exception, future

Is it possible for an exception to be thrown, escaping the `Future` context?

Since a `Future` "evaluates" as soon as it's defined:

is it possible for the definition of a `Future` to throw an exception, passing through the `Future` context?

```
scala> Future { Thread.sleep(3000); println("3 seconds elapsed"); 100 }
res2: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = 
     scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@56113384

scala> 3 seconds elapsed
```

I could not come up with such an example.

```
scala> Future { throw new Exception("Foo!") }
res3: scala.concurrent.Future[Nothing] = 
  scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@47a86fbb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but maybe not quite the way you're thinking of. According to the [source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/52fde52920d93325310e5544991feeea03e5c763/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Future.scala#L24), only errors that are *not* `NonFatal` will escape `Future.apply`.

```
 try Success(body) catch { case NonFatal(e) => Failure(e) }
```

i.e. exceptions like: `VirtualMachineError`, `OutOfMemoryError`,`StackOverflowError`, `ThreadDeath`, `LinkageError`, `InterruptedException`, `ControlThrowable`.. will go uncaught as they represent a fatal JVM error that you will not be able to handle.

Comment: StackOverflowError is actually considered non-fatal for some reason

Comment: Scaladocs say otherwise: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.util.control.NonFatal$  Perhaps they are incorrect?

Comment: I ran this REPL per what @dwickern said: `scala> try { throw new StackOverflowError("...") } catch { case NonFatal(e) => "caught it" }
java.lang.StackOverflowError: ...
  at .liftedTree1$1(<console>:12)
  ... 33 elided`

Comment: Hmm. Apparently they changed StackOverflowError to fatal some time between 2.10 and 2.11: https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/64603653f82082431941cb29ad317b669822f28e

Answer (score 0):

A future in itself does nothing except define the computation. It just so happens to be you're using one of the constructors (or apply methods) that, by default, begins running the computation immediately. The mixing of exception handling and concurrency is one of the issues that, unfortunately, not explicit with scala.concurrent.Future. A better alternative may be to use `scalaz.concurrent.Task` which combines error handling with explicit concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to throw an error from your future?

Future is a monad which will handles latency and exceptions while you are dealing with it.

If you look at Future implementation it looks like as below,

```
trait Future[T] {    def onComplete(callback: Try[T] => Unit)(implicit exe..) }
```

So when as soon as your future gets complete and value available your callback method will be invoked and return unit.

If you see callback method you will get idea your result would be success or error and Try[T] woluld manage all the things for you.

Comment: I don't want to throw an exception from a Future. I want to know if it's possible.